# Soldier's Shovel

Tags: halacha, shiurim-measurements, bathroom, army-military-war, ki-teitzei

Is there a shiur for the item the soldier is obligated to carry in [Devarim 23:14](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9987#v=14)?

> וְיָתֵד תִּהְיֶה לְךָ עַל אֲזֵנֶךָ וְהָיָה בְּשִׁבְתְּךָ חוּץ וְחָפַרְתָּה בָהּ וְשַׁבְתָּ וְכִסִּיתָ אֶת צֵאָתֶךָ
>
> And you shall keep a stake in addition to your weapons; and it shall be, when you sit down outside [to relieve yourself], you shall dig with it, and you shall return and cover your excrement.

That is, what types of items qualify for this mitzvah, and what size must they be?

Comment: Why "you shall return" - and not "you shall sit/squat"?

Comment: Perhaps when one aquires a shovel, he has an obligation to go back and cover poops that he made without the benefit of a shovel.

Comment: Looking at the targums, I would be tempted to say it means "and turn around".

Answer (score 1):

```
That is, what types of items qualify for this mitzvah, and what size must they be?
```

Surely the answer is **any thing that gets the job done**!

Comment: Why "surely"? ()

Comment: Generally speaking things in Halacha have shiurim, even if you could get the job done with less. e.g. the minimum length of a Shofar. Note that the Torah here specifically requires a utensil of some kind, even though you could theoretically get the job done without it.

Comment: @Yishai - agreed. But since we don't find a shiur, not in the Mishna and not in the Rambam, then we have to assume that there is no minimum shiur.

Comment: so can carrying a pen or a key fulfill the mitzva?

Comment: @ClintEastwood - why not? If you can dig a hole big enough with it to relieve yourself, and then use it to cover it up when you're done, then it qualifies.

Comment: What if you carry a pen or a key which is theoretically big enough to dig a hole with, but in practice you always use your hands to dig the hole because it's easier?

Comment: @Daniel, I don't understand what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Would you be yotzei the "mitzvah of shovel" if you carried an object which theoretically could be used as a shovel even if you have absolutely no intention of using it as a shovel?

Comment: I guess that would depend : if you relieved yourself and would not use it, rather you' d leave everything uncovered then why would it qualify? Since the passuk explicitly explains how to use it.